# keyerror:0 though index starts from 0

Tags: python-3.x, indexing

this is my dataset.[image: brand6 is the name of the dataframe]

I basically want the number of words in each list from the words column. this is my code

```
for ind,word in enumerate(brand6['words']):
  brand6['len']=len(brand6[ind][word])
```

However, i am getting an error like this:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\darshini.nagaraj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item


  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 0
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\darshini.nagaraj\Desktop\example.py", line 28, in <module>
print((brand6[ind][word]))

  File "C:\Users\darshini.nagaraj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\darshini.nagaraj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

 File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 0
```

I have been working for 3 days on this. any help will be much appreciated!!
Thanks well in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
word_count=[]
for i in range(brand6.shape[0]):
   word_count.append(len(brand6['words'][i]))
brand6['word_count']=word_count
```

the last line will create a new column as 'word_count' in your dataset.

Comment: glad to help keep going.